# nohttp resource was found that matches the request uri

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to develop an api that allows both get and post requests at the same address.

```
public class DataController : ApiController
{

   [HttpGet]
   public DataResponse Foo()
   {
     return GetNext();
   }

   [HttpPost]
   public void Foo(long p1, string p2)
   {
     SaveValue(p1,p2);
   }
}
```

`GET` works fine. When calling the `POST` method, I get the following error:

> the requested resource does not support http method 'POST'

[image]

My WebApiConfig looks like the following:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
  {
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
      config.EnableCors();
      config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
      config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html"));
      config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name: "DefaultApi", routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}");
    }
  }
```

Any idea what I need to change to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in two ways-

1- Change the way you are calling API i.e - pass values in url like `<url>?p1=value&p2=value`

2- Change the signature of the Action in Web API to

```
public void Foo([FromBody] MyContract data)
```

where `MyContract` is a class with two properties

```
public class MyContract
{
    public long p1 { get; set; }
    public string p2 { get; set; }
}
```

This is because by default parameter binding is done through URL and you are passing them through body.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Ipsit. Works like a charm :-)